# Change decimal mark

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I'd like to test some functions in my browser but don't know where to switch the settings so that the decimal mark changes.

```
(1.53).toLocaleString()
```

returns 1,53 (e.g I'd like to see the US version 1.53)

In windows I already changed the decimal mark under region and language but it doesn't seem to affect the browsers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `locales` argument ("a string with a BCP 47 language tag, or an array of such strings") to [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString):

```js
console.log((1.53).toLocaleString('en-US'));
```