# Number.toLocaleString() with custom separators

Tags: javascript, locale, number-formatting

I need to format a number in JavaScript with separators that may be defined at runtime.

The combination of thousand and decimal separator may not match a specific locale.

Is there a way to provide the thousand and decimal separator in JavaScript `toLocaleString()`? or to use `NumberFormat` explicitly with values I define?

I see examples using locale codes, and some using other values ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString ) but these don't cover my use case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994133/change-decimal-mark/37994346#37994346

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I do not know the expected decimal and thousand separator until runtime so setting a locale is not feasible for this example.

Comment: There are practically three different separators, `,`, `.` and space, it's possible to detect the correct combination at runtime, and pick a suitable language tag. Or are the delimiters fully custom, like `a`, `x` etc.?

Comment: @Teemu They are certainly at the moment only standard separators, but it's possible they could be switched about based on the installation. 
You're right that the correct combination could be detected but I'm not sure of the best way to approach this, do you have any suggestions.

Comment: Create an object and name the properties according to separator combinations. Something like in [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7m5rjnjt/). I just couldn't figure out a locale using space as thousand separator and decimal point, maybe you'll find it.

Comment: Interesting solution! I don't think the customer at the moment would like using a locale which doesn't match their country (even though they expect custom (non standard) formats) go figure! but this is worth knowing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option is to format to a string with known separators, and then do a find/replace with the unknown separators.

```
function formatNum(num, separator, fraction) {
  var str = num.toLocaleString('en-US');
  str = str.replace(/\./, fraction);
  str = str.replace(/,/g, separator);
  return str;
}

formatNum(12342.2, "a", "x");
//12a342x2
```

Comment: This is both a sensible and horrible solution! I both hate and love it!

Comment: THIS is in fact a very clever and elegant solution larry! As long the en-US format doens't change everthign should be fine!

Comment: Important note: With this code, the fraction  symbol anything except "," as all commas will be replaced by the thousands separator.

Comment: num.toLocaleString('fullwide') should work better and to get rid of potential scientific format

Answer (score 1):

The original answer on this page won't work if a comma is used as the decimal separator (the parameter `fraction`). That's problematic, because comma is used as the decimal separator widely e.g. [in Europe](https://www.smartick.com/blog/other-contents/curiosities/decimal-separators/#Europe) (Spain, France, Norway, Czechia, Denmark...).

In order to make it work, the replacement can be done in two steps instead using an intermediate placeholder for the fraction symbol:

```
function formatNum(num, separator, fraction) {
    return num
        .toLocaleString('en-US');
        .replace(/\./, "<fraction>")
        .replace(/,/g, separator)
        .replace(/<fraction>/, fraction);
}

formatNum(12342.2, " ", ",");
//12 342,2
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a `Intl.NumberFormat` method called [`formatToParts`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/formatToParts) with enough granularity to do this correctly.

Here's changing all thousand separators to underscore:

```js
const formatter = Intl.NumberFormat(undefined); // Undefined locale == use the user's resolved locale

const parts = formatter.formatToParts(123456789.987654321);
parts.filter(p => p.type === 'group').forEach(p => p.value = '_');
const formatted = parts.map(p => p.value).join('');
formatted // '123_456_789.988'
```

FWIW, the `formatToParts()` return value looks like this:

```js
[{type: 'integer',  value: '123'},
 {type: 'group',    value: ','  },
 {type: 'integer',  value: '456'},
 {type: 'group',    value: ','  },
 {type: 'integer',  value: '789'},
 {type: 'decimal',  value: '.'  },
 {type: 'fraction', value: '988'}]
```

..so if you need to adjust the decimal separator, it's easy as well.

If the MDN doc doesn't have enough detail [the ecma 402 spec covers these parts](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-partitionnotationsubpattern).